# Why are Puppet classes called class?

Tags: puppet

I'm quite new to Puppet, and so far I worked through the official [tutorial](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/), at least the introduction and part 1. So I guess I should have a basic understanding of how Puppet works and its terminology.

Anyway, there is one thing I don't get: In Puppet you have classes, which basically are nothing but outsourced manifests. So far, so good.

But why are they called `class`?

I have an OOP and CSS background, and I can also imagine the general concept of a class as a *container* for objects that have something in common. But none of these definitions match the concept of a `class` in Puppet. At least I don't get the analogy.

Can anybody bring some light into this?

*PS: I know that there is no objective answer to this question, but primarily opinion-based, but I don't know where to ask elsewhere, so I hope for some advice :-)*

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's recommended by Puppet and I'm sure it says this in the docs somewhere that you make classes for each of your node's roles that each contain `require`s for all other classes needed by that role with the same requires in multiple role classes if need be (which is allowed when you use the `require` command rather than `include`). This way you could have self contained classes such as 'fileserver' or 'webserver' which just need to be included in the `node` resources.

More on overlapping role classes:

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_classes.html#aside-history-the-future-and-best-practices

Comment: Note you just need 50 reputation to comment on other answers (http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Try to so we can comment my answer instead of you doing it through suggestions like http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3279277

Answer (score 1):

You can relate Classes in puppet with division or separation of manifest bases on its role.

Classes are named blocks of Puppet code which are not applied unless they are invoked by name.

For the modularity and understanding of manifest it is recommended that different role of manifest code should be present in different file, which is called as classes.

And the name of class should denote its role. For example user(to create user), params(to pass parameters).